# Descriptor not working when pytest with fixture run before

Tags: python, pytest

I have a class where I use a descriptor to prevent changes to some of its attributes.

```
class Frozen:
    """cannot change attribute if it already exists"""

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.storage_name = name

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if self.storage_name in instance.__dict__:
            raise AttributeError(
                f'readonly attribute {value.__class__.__name__}')
        else:
            instance.__dict__[self.storage_name] = value

Class Patient:

    first_name = Frozen()
    email = Frozen()

    def __init__(self, first_name: str, email: str, phone: str, age: int, gender: str, last_name="", weekly_meals: WeeklyMeals = None, nutrition_plan: NutritionPlan = None) -> None:
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.email = email
        self.phone = phone
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender
        self.weekly_meals = weekly_meals
        self.nutrition_plan = nutrition_plan
        self.receipt_line_mapping = dict()
        self.meals = list()
```

I have around 40 tests that was working fine, but now I add one that made this one failed:

```
def test_cannot_change_patient_email():
    p = r.random_patient('Fulano')

    with pytest.raises(AttributeError):
        p.email = 'Ciclano'
```

This new test has a session fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture
def session(in_memory_db):
    start_mappers()
    yield sessionmaker(bind=in_memory_db)()
    clear_mappers()
```

and that is what is causing the problem. I use this fixture in many other test, but until now the failing test was the first test file to run. The new test I just added changed that, as it became the first to run. And that brought to my knowledge that any test that I run with this fixture (even the old ones) will cause this problem. Now, I don't know if this is a problem I have to fix in the way I did the descriptor, or the fixture, or the test itself.

This is the pytest fail I get:

```
================================== FAILURES ==================================
___________________ test_cannot_change_patient_first_name ____________________
/tests/test_model.py:162: in test_cannot_change_patient_first_name
    p.first_name = 'Ciclano'
E   Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'AttributeError'>
______________________ test_cannot_change_patient_email ______________________
/tests/test_model.py:169: in test_cannot_change_patient_email
    p.email = 'Ciclano'
E   Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'AttributeError'>
```

and this is the error message I was expecting (and that would make the test pass):

```
Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep  9 2021, 23:20:13) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tests.random_refs as r
>>> p = r.random_patient('ze')
>>> p.first_name = 'fadf'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jap/projects/vlep/app/src/vlep/domain/model.py", line 80, in __set__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: readonly attribute str
```

tks

Comment: Please post the error message and traceback

Comment: Don't upload images of code if you can help it https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: tks again @Tzane

Comment: I created a similar test to test for `AttributeError` and it works as expected. Does the test work if you just run the test individually? If it only fails when run with the full suite, it could be that the other tests you run somehow change what `r.random_patient('Fulano')` returns.

Comment: the rand still works. The problem is that the patient name changes with `patient.first_name = Ciclano` and it should not. This is caused by the session fixture some how.

Comment: Does it work without the fixture? And what package are the fixture functions from?

Comment: It works whenever this failing test is ran first. If I run any other test that use this fixture before it, it will fail. The fixture is used to create sqlalchemy class mappers and yield a session using sqlite. I am running 40+ tests in 7 diffent files and this `AttributeError` is the only failing because of this fixture.

Comment: I just changed the test to see if `'first_name' in p.__dict__` would return `True` and it does. I don't know what is going on. I am guessing `instance.__dict__` is not returning what I expect, because the name change is taking place. Or that the `Frozen` descriptor is just not working.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the descriptor. The descriptor is a class attribute of `Patient` meaning a new `Frozen` is only instantiated once on class definition of `Patient`, i.e. you are getting the same instance of `Frozen` even if you have a new `Patient` instance. I think this is the reason there are values in `__dict__` unexpectedly. I read a bit of [descriptors Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#complete-practical-example) and came up with this for a `Frozen` descriptor of my own:

```
class Frozen:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.private_name = '_' + name

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if hasattr(obj, self.private_name):
            raise AttributeError("Set once")
        else:
            setattr(obj, self.private_name, value)

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return getattr(obj, self.private_name)
```

It stores the attribute values in a "private" member of `Patient` instead. This isn't a truly unmutable, but that's not to my knowledge even possible to do in Python.

You might want to check how dataclasses deals with "fzozen" attributes: https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#frozen-instances

Comment: still not working. They way u propose I will have a `name` attribute that, when first called, will create a `_name` and set its value. It will be frozen when using `self.name`, but not when using `self._name`. The way i am using it I will have only `name`, but them I need to have different setter and getter methods to avoid recursion error with `__getattr__` (that I don't know if could bring me problems latter on). I tried frozen, but it doesn't work well with classical mapping on sqlalchemy.